# How to change the values of a sub column in a pandas pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table dataframe and i need to change the values of a sub-column of the dataframe

Need to change the values of sub-column **Comment** (if it is >= 1, 'Yes', else 'No')

`data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Comment'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)`
   
 `data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`
    
`tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame1.columns]`
   
 `data_frame1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)`

**Input Dataframe**

```
PC Geo Comp  Month          Bill1 Bill2  Comment
A  Ind   OS  01/10/2019     1     1.28      1
A  Ind   OS  01/11/2019     1     1.28      2
A  Ind   OS  01/12/2019     1     1.28      0
```

**output**

```
               OCT-19                  Nov-19               Dec-19
             Bill1 Bill2 comment   Bill1 Bill2 comment   Bill1 Bill2 comment     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28    1        1    1.28    2         1    1.28   0
```

**Desired output**

```
                   OCT-19               Nov-19              Dec-19
             Bill1 Bill2 Comment Bill1 Bill2 Comment Bill1 Bill2 Comment     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1.28    Yes     1    1.28  Yes        1    1.28 No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change it before `pivot_table`, because column is removed. Reason is default aggregate function in `pivot_table` is `mean` working only with numeric, so all non numeric columns are dropped.

So is necessary change it after, one possible solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], 
                             values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Comment'], 
                             columns=['Month'], 
                             fill_value=0)

data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

mask = data_frame1.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'Comment'
data_frame1.loc[:, mask] = np.where(data_frame1.loc[:, mask] >= 1, 'Yes', 'No')
print (data_frame1)
Month       01/10/2019               01/11/2019               01/12/2019  \
                 Bill1 Bill2 Comment      Bill1 Bill2 Comment      Bill1   
PC Geo Comp                                                                
A  Ind OS            1  1.28     Yes          1  1.28     Yes          1   

Month                      
            Bill2 Comment  
PC Geo Comp                
A  Ind OS    1.28      No
```

Answer (score 1):

Before doing any operation on loaded data_frame, apply the below function:

```
def change_comment(comment_value):
    if int(comment_value)>=1:
        return "Yes"
    return "No"

data_frame = data_frame[["comment"]].applymap(change_comment)
```

Hope this helps!!!